# Creating a method to print a previously created array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

In the assignment I'm working on I have created a couple of different arrays and am now asked to write a method that will print these arrays. I am to call it once from main using the first array I created and call it a second time from main using the other array I created. I'm pretty sure I know how to call this method from main to pass these arrays to the method, but am stuck as to how to write this method to print them. Here is what I have so far, although I know it's not much.

```
 public static void(double[] arrays) {
```

and here are the arrays I have created.

```
double[] floatsArray = new double[5];
double[] floatingArray = {1.6, 2.5, 4.1, 7.3};
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How do you print one `double` value?

Comment: Is that really all there is to it, just write the method header and write a print statement just like I was just printing any other variable? That's what I thought initially, but figured that had to be too easy with the stuff we've been covering lately ha.

Comment: 1) You have to put a name to a method, for example `public static void printArray(double[] array)` 2) Use a `loop` for iterate the array 3) Print them with `System.out.print()` or/and `System.out.println()`

Comment: Thanks @nachokk I guess now my question would be how to write this since I'm calling the arrays from main and not in the method itself?

Comment: You pass them by parameter. you create in main method and then call , `printArray(floatingArray )`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help, it works :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through each individual element in the array using a for loop

```
 public static void printArray(double[] array) 
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
       System.out.println(array[i])
    }
 }
```

Or, you can use java's for-each loop that uses an iterator to access each individual element in the array

```
 public static void printArray(double[] array) 
 {    
    for (double value : array) 
    {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
 }
```